# When retreiving state of data-table from vuex, pagination is not updated

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

In vue 3.9.3, vuetify 2.0, vuex
I have a v-data-table and I saved in a store the options (page, sortBy, ...)

If page is set to n in store.options, the data is fetched and go to page n but the pagination stays to page 1 all though it is page 3 displayed

How can I update the pagination ?

```
data() {
  return {
    ...
    options: {}
    ...
  }
},
created() {
  // this.$store.state.options : {"page":2,"itemsPerPage":10,"sortBy":['name'],"sortDesc":[],"groupBy":[],"groupDesc":[],"mustSort":false,"multiSort":false}
  this.options = this.$store.state.options
  this.dataGet()
},
methods: {
  dataGet() {
    this.$store.commit('optionsSave', { options: this.options })

    axios.get(...)
     .then(function (r) {
       ...
     }
  },
  watch: {
    options: {
      handler() {
        this.dataGet()
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }

  ...
```

Comment: the implementation of pagination changed with vuetify 2. Do you use the external pagination?
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101
Please provide your code inside template.

Comment: code  : https://codepen.io/flahol/pen/GVEgVV?editors=1010

Comment: I always used `:pagination.sync` instead of `:options.sync`. But I am not sure if it is still available with vuetify 2

Comment: Hi there,

I know this question is old but is there any chance @PatriceFlao that you managed to have the pagination right?

I've open a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109352/vuetify-v-data-table-pagination-options-page-value-changes-in-mounted